# Understanding the proof of $\text{T}_pX= \text{Ker}\text{D}_pf$.

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

Define $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Let $a$ be a regular value of f (i.e. $\forall p \in f^{-1}(a), \text{D}_pf$ is surjective),  $X = f^{-1}(a)$ and choose $p \in X$. Then $\text{T}_pX= \text{Ker}\text{D}_pf$,
where $\text{T}_pX$ is the tangent plane of $X$ in $p$.

We defined also:
$\text{T}_pX = \{ v= c'(0) \text{ st } c:]-\epsilon, \epsilon[ \to \mathbb{R}^N  \text{ derivable}, c(0) = p \text{ and } \text{Im}c \subset X \}$.

I want to understand the proof of $\text{T}_pX= \text{Ker}\text{D}_pf$ which starts like this in our lecture notes:

$\text{dim}\text{KerD}_pf = N-m$ since $\text{D}_pf$ surjective.
It suffices to show $\text{T}_pX \subset \text{Ker}\text{D}_pf$. Why do we only have to show this inclusion?

Comment: $X$ is $N-m$ dimensional smoothly embedded orientable boundary-less submanifold of $\Bbb R^N$. In particular, $X$ is a manifold of dimension $N-m$. Now, the dimension of the tangent space at any point of a $k$-dimensional manifold is $k$.

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. These are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a finite-dimensional vector space, and two subspaces of the same dimension such that one is contained in the other, they're necessarily equal. The dimensions of $T_pM$ and $\ker Df_p$ are equal, so it suffices to show one of the inclusions. And $T_pM \subseteq \ker Df_p$ is the easiest one, because if $f(c(t)) = a$ for all $t$, what happens when you take the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$?